# Macro find and replace to change string to date

Tags: excel, vba

I used the macro to find and replacement function to change the string to date. It worked well with some of the dates but went wrong also. 
The code I used is:

```
Worksheets(“Sheet 1”).Columns(“H”).Replace What:=“.”,
Replacement:=“/“,
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns,
MatchCase:=True
```

The original string is `"11.01.2019"` and the date should be `11/01/2019` which is `11 January 2019`.

But when I used the macro, it was converted to `01/11/2019`, which is **1 November 2019**.

The code worked well if the day is bigger than 12.

For example `"13.01.2019"` will be converted to `13/01/2019` correctly.

Anyone can help with the code to make it work properly?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are the original strings consistently formatted as `dd.mm.yyyy`, or do some of them have single-digit days or months?

Comment: Hi jsheeran. Thanks for your reply. Yes the original strings are consistently formatted as dd.mm.yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when `Windows` regional settings tells `Excel` that `English` date format `D/M/Y` shall be used.

Then the default date delimiter is `/` as in en_US too but the sequence of the date parts differs from en_US (`M/D/Y`). When `VBA` runs, it always runs in en_US locale settings and so it gets `11/01/2019` to be November 1. 2019 in `VBA`already. But `13/01/2019` is not a date in en_US. So `VBA` does not converting it into a date. The `Excel` then converts the string "13/01/2019" into the correct date according to Windows regional settigs.

Workaround:

Do using [Range.TextToColumns method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) instead.

```
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Columns("H:H").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("H1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlDMYFormat)
```

You needs avoiding calling the `TextToColumns` more than one times. Because then `VBA` will reconverting the `D/M/Y` dates into en_US `M/D/Y` again if possible.

Comment: Hi Axel Richter. Thanks for your help! It worked well!

Answer (score 0):

I recall that VBA automatically assumes [American date notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_States). 
Try:

```
Worksheets(“Sheet 1”).Columns(8).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyy"

Worksheets(“Sheet 1”).Columns(“H”).Replace What:=“.”, Replacement:=“/“, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will construct a date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, which should be accepted regardless of your locality, and populate the cell accordingly (but formatted according to your system settings).

```
Dim r As Range, cell As Range
Set r = [H2:H999] ' or wherever your data is
For Each cell In r
  cell = Right(cell, 4) & "-" & Right(Left(cell, 5), 2) & "-" & Left(cell, 2)
Next cell
```